# Android ScrollView resets when SeekBar moves

Tags: android, scrollview, seekbar

I have a an activity which has a custom layout, with SeekBar and a ScrollView. Whenever I move the seekbar programmatically, the scrollview resets to top ( meaning onLayout gets called ), how do I set it so that the ScrollView doesn't get reset ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should not create row (in `getView()` method) again and again..

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
             View row = arg1;
             if(row==null)
                {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);

                }
           //  Log.d("position", ""+str[position]);
                Button b1 = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btn);
                 final SeekBar s1 = (SeekBar)row.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
                //s1.setFocusable(true);
                b1.setText(str[position]);
                   b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                   {
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Progress is "+s1.getProgress()+"%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }

                  });  

        return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have this same issue, and so far I have been unable to solve it.

I tried several things like during the SeekBar onStartTrackingTouch setting the scoll on my ScrollView called quickScroll. This worked in terms of setting the scroll, but every time the progress changed on the seekBar the ScrollView would quickly reset and then return to the set position.

```
@Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            quickScroll.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //quickScroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    //quickScroll.setEnabled(false);
                     quickScroll.scrollTo(0, 54);
                    // quickScroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                } 
            });


    }
```

Among many other things as you can see, however, when onLayout gets called on my custom viewGroup it resets the Scroll to (0,0). As it stands my onLayout() gets called on every button press, but only resets the ScrollView when the SeekBar is changed. Please let me know if you have found a solution to this.